# Wordpress - Remove submenu from custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type named portfolio with tag taxonomy support.

Since WP does not make a difference between post tags and custom post type tags, I created a menu item Taxonomy under which I want to put categories and post tags. I managed to create the the menu and submenus, and also remove category and post tags from the Post menu, but i didn't manage to remove Post Tags from the custom post type menu.

I tried:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&post_type=portfolio' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit dirty, but it works:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_niggly_bits');
function remove_niggly_bits() {
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=portfolio'][11]);
}
```

I'm not sure exactly which key number you'll want to remove. Best way to find that is to do:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_niggly_bits');
function remove_niggly_bits() {
    global $submenu;
    //unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=portfolio'][11]);
    print_r($submenu); exit;
}
```

Everything will break when you load the admin area until you remove that line, but it'll show you the structure and which key you need.

Comment: It is a bit dirty. I hoped for it to work with remove_submenu_page(), but since it is the only (working) answer you get the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 20):

You can use `remove_submenu_page()` - the trick however is to get the slug exactly right, to do this the easiest way is to dump the global $submenu and check for the menu_slug and submenu_slug.

```
global $submenu;
var_dump($submenu);
```

This will give you the array of menus, the top level key is the menu_slug and then the correct submenu_slug can be found in the element 2 of the nested arrays.

So if I had a custom post type called "my_events" and I wanted to remove the tags menu from it, my original menu structure would look like this

```
...
'edit.php?post_type=my_events' => 
    array
      5 => 
        array
          0 => string 'All Events' (length=10)
          1 => string 'edit_posts' (length=10)
          2 => string 'edit.php?post_type=my_events' (length=28)
      10 => 
        array
          0 => string 'Add New' (length=7)
          1 => string 'edit_posts' (length=10)
          2 => string 'post-new.php?post_type=my_events' (length=32)
      15 => 
        array
          0 => string 'Tags' (length=4)
          1 => string 'manage_categories' (length=17)
          2 => string 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&amp;post_type=my_events' (length=55)
...
```

From this you can see that the menu_slug is `'edit.php?post_type=my_events'` and the submenu slug for the tags menu is `'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&amp;post_type=my_events'`.

So the remove function call would be:

```
remove_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=my_events', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&amp;post_type=my_events');
```

Note that the submenu slug is html encoded so the ampersand is now `&amp;` - this is probably that thing that has made it hard for people to work out from first principles what the slug name should be.

Comment: +1 confirmed it works. As reported elsewhere, this function is very sensitive to getting both arguments spot on. It's worth persisting with different tweaks to get it right.

Comment: +1 SUPER HELPFUL! Thanks @benz001
Should be the correct answer.

Comment: The encoded character & was an important tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to just use the `'show_ui' => false`.

```
function car_brand_init() {
    // new taxonomy named merk
    register_taxonomy(
        'merk',
        'lease_fop',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Merken' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'merken' ),
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            // use this to hide from menu
            'show_ui' => false,
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'car_brand_init' );
```

Comment: But this also disables the meta box. If you want to only hide the taxonomy from the menu, @benz001 solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer from benz001:

No need to do the var dump to get the slug right. This worked for me.

```
remove_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=POST_TYPE', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=TAXONOMY_SLUG&amp;post_type=POST_TYPE')
```

First argument, replace POST_TYPE with what you see in your URL field at the top of the browser when viewing archive in back end.

Second Argument: Left click on the submenu you want to remove, copy the link, remove the last forward slash and everything to the left of it. Replace the & with &amp;

Second arg example below.

1 Copy and paste submenu link

```
http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_custom_taxonomy&post_type=your_custom_post
```

2 Remove last forward slash and everything left of it.

```
edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_custom_taxonomy&post_type=your_custom_post
```

3 Replace the & with the HTML entity &amp;

```
/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_custom_taxonomy&amp;post_type=your_custom_post
```